# How to export a require assigned to a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, vue.js, electron

I'm doing the following to make this `require` to become visible in `<app></app>`

**index.html:**

```
<script>
  var electron = require('electron')
</script>
<app></app>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

**App.vue:**

```
const ipc = electron.ipcRenderer
console.log(ipc)
```

But I get `un-used` and `un-defined` var errors with ESLint, so I decided to do this:

**requires.js:**

```
var electron = require('electron')

exports.electron = electron
```

**index.html:**

```
  <script src="requires.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <app></app>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

But now I get this error: `requires.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`.

What the correct way to export and import the electron `require`?

**Note:** requiring `electron` directly in `App.vue` doesn't work. You can only require `electron` in `index.html`

**Full example:** https://github.com/alexcheninfo/vue-electron-simple

Comment: Maybe `module.exports` instead of `exports`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be trying to do here is define `electron` as a global variable; for that to work you can set `window.electron = require('electron')` in your index.html in the first example. (It will be available in you bundle.js)

However, using globals for this bad practice and not necessary. What you should do, is just use `require` in your code. You say this doesn't work: the reason why it doesn't is probably that you're using webpack or something similar to create `bundle.js`. Furthermore, you probably run the bundling process in Node and not in Electron, therefore `require('electron')` does not work as expected. Note that it works in your `index.html` which is not part of the bundle.

If you want to continue to use this setup, you could rename Electron's require to distinguish between the `require` resolved during bundling and the `require` resolved at runtime. In other words, `window.electronRequire = require` in the script tag of `index.html` and then use `electronRequire('electron')` in your code.

Having said that, why bundle everything in the first place? Electron has full Node integration so you can use regular Node modules; the files are not sent via HTTP either so there is little to gain from bundling everything into one file.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Well, I'm using Vue.js which uses `.vue` files. Webpack compiles them into JavaScript. But I think you're right, I'll consider not bundling the code.